# Is this a dangling sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntax, imperative-sentences, implication

Below is a paragraph I've come across on BBC. Is the first sentence dangling?

The paragraph is introduced earlier in the article as part of a section in which business leaders "share their plans or thoughts on running a business in 2017".

> ***Include a regular slot in the working day or week for staff to work out together or alone, followed by a healthy communal lunch.*** This is a great way of bringing staff together socially, whilst improving their physical and mental health. This leads to a happier, more productive and collaborative workforce.

Should the first word be *including*?

From http://www.bbc.com/news/business-38287871

Comment: I think "include" is in its imperative form here. In the context of the article, since it's giving you tips, I think it makes sense.

Comment: It might help to imagine a 'You must' tacked onto the front of this sentence if you suspect it is the imperative form. Thus, 'You must include a regular slot....' is correct where 'You must including a regular slot...' is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually certain kinds of ambiguous or ungrammatical participles or modifiers--not sentences--that are characterized as dangling.

Dangling occurs as "a modifier without a head or as a participle without an implied subject, as *leaving the tunnel* in *The daylight was blinding, leaving the tunnel."* (http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dangling)

The first clause of the instant sentence may appear to have no subject, but one is clearly implied  (eg, *you, one,* or *people who run businesses)*, as is also a verb (eg, *should, must).*

Thus no dangling occurs.

Answer (score 1):

English 2nd-person command or imperative form is the infinitive form of the verb without *to* in front it.  *You* or *you all* can optionally be placed before it for clarity/emphasis.  That's what *include* is doing here.

Changing *include* to *including* would make *including* a verbal, and that would make the sentence dangling, as *to work out* is a verbal but there is no other normal verb in the sentence.